# Find an expression of the direction field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, vectors

I have a directions vector field which I got empirically using quiver in Matlab. I want to find some analytical expressions that might work at least in part of the direction field. How can I find/propose some candidate analytical differential equations $f'(x,y)$? Is there a kind of catalog out there from which I can draw and see?

It's a big field, but here's a partial view of it:

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common method for fitting an analytical scalar field $F(\textbf{x})$ (in any dimension) to a vector field of (potentially noisy) derivatives is to expand the field in a radial basis function

$$ F(\textbf{x}) = \sum_i a_ie^{-|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}|^2/2\sigma^2} $$

where you pick a grid of centres $\textbf{x}_i$. Then you can find the $a_i$ and $\sigma$ that optimise the fit to the gradients (it involves a simple matrix inversion). See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.2531.pdf) for useful reading.

Here are the details:

- Pick a grid of $n$ points $\textbf{x}_i$ that cover the space you're interested in. It's wise to make them the most dense-packing possible. So in 2D they would form a [hexagonal lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing), in 3D they would be [face-centered cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing), etc. The $\sigma$ parameter will equal the lattice parameter of this grid.
- We'll denote the 'measurements' of $\nabla F(\textbf{x})$ at each of the lattice points as $\textbf{G}_i\equiv \nabla F(\textbf{x}_i)$.
- All we need to do is find the vector $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ that minimises the metric

$$ E(a)= \sum_{k=1}^n \Bigg|\textbf{G}_k- \sum_{k'=1}^n a_{k'}\nabla e^{-|\textbf{x}_k-\textbf{x}_{k'}|/2\sigma^2}\Bigg|^2 $$

- This metric is minimised when
  $$ Ba=c $$
  where the matrix $B$ is
  \begin{align} B_{k,k'}&=\sum_{k''=1}^n \nabla e^{-|\textbf{x}_k-\textbf{x}_{k''}|/2\sigma^2}\cdot\nabla e^{-|\textbf{x}_{k''}-\textbf{x}_{k'}|/2\sigma^2}\\
  &=\sum_{k''=1}^n \Lambda_k^{k''}\cdot\Lambda_{k''}^{k'} \end{align}
  and the vector $c$ is
  \begin{align} c_k &= \sum_{k'=1}^n \nabla e^{-|\textbf{x}_k-\textbf{x}_{k'}|/2\sigma^2}\cdot \textbf{G}_{k'} \\
  &=\sum_{k'=1}^n \Lambda_k^{k'}\cdot\textbf{G}_{k'} \end{align}
  where, to simplify things, I've defined the vectors

$$ \Lambda_i^j\equiv\nabla e^{-|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j|^2/2\sigma} = -(\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j)\sigma^{-2}e^{-|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j|^2/2\sigma} $$

- The implementation is a bit easier and more efficient if you precompute the tensor $\Lambda$ before constructing $B$ and $c$.
- Finally, you find $a$ by applying [linsolve](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html) to $B$ and $c$.

Comment: Fantastic. Doesn't sound easy but will try. Thanks!

Comment: @OliverAmundsen It's surprisingly straightforward - let me know if you get stuck. Note that your grid of centres $\textbf{x}_i$ do not need to be very dense - I suggest you initially pick a lattice that is about $100\times$ less dense than the one you display in your image.

Comment: Thanks! So, in matlab it would be for instance a nonlinear least square fit (nlinfit), given the equation @F(X) ... it'd run something like that, correct? or any other simpler way?

Comment: Actually it's a linear system that needs to be solved, $AX=B$ where $A$ and $B$ are known, so you'd use the linsolve function to obtain $X$ (which is a vector of the $a_i$ parameters). And it's usually adequate to set the $\sigma$ parameter equal to the spacing of your centres $\textbf{x}_i$, so you don't necessarily need to optimise that.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what would be the $A$ and the $B$?

Comment: thanks so much, it'll take me some time to digest this as my math knowledge to quickly understand all the notation/subscripts to build $B$, $\Lambda$ isn't that great. I'll try to start coding today, and maybe I could share with you the code if at all possible.

Comment: One clarification. $\bf{x}_i - \bf{x}_j $ is the euclidean distance between $\textbf{x}_i = (x_i,y_i)$ and $\textbf{x}_j = (x_j,y_j)$ ??

Comment: @OliverAmundsen $\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j=(x_i-x_j,y_i-y_j)$. The Euclidean distance is $|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j|=\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2}$.

Comment: So, the $\Lambda_i^j$ is actually 2 tensors? one for the $x$ and another for the $y$? Sorry for the trivial questions @ozo

Comment: @OliverAmundsen Yes, each $\Lambda_i^j$ element is in fact a vector. So you can either store a pair of matrices - one for each component - or you could create a 2D array of vectors.

Comment: yes sorry. I'm confused on how to calculate $B$. Can't understand the $k$, $k'$ and $k''$. Do they indicate that the $\Lambda$ is transposed?. In Matlab i got $\Lambda_i^j$ as: (for i = 1 : n; X(i,:) = x(i) - x; end). How should I get the $\Lambda$'s for $B$?

Comment: @OliverAmundsen it will involve three nested for-loops. I'm not familiar with matlab but it'll be something like: for i=1:n, for j=1:n, B(i,j)=0, for k=1:n, B(i,j)+=dot(Lambda(i,k),Lambda(k,j)), end, end, end

Comment: 2 questions: (1) I got two $\Lambda$'s one for $x$'s other for $y$'s (let's $\Lambda_x$ and $\Lambda_y$). Should I have a single $B$ and a single $c$ or two? If only one, then the in the eq. for $B_{k,k'}$ above, should I do the dot product with $\Lambda_x$ over $\Lambda_y$? (2) Matrix $\bf G$ is represents the current values of the arrow angles, or their gradient? Thx!

Comment: In my maths above, $\Lambda=(\Lambda_x,\Lambda_y)$ so the dot products will be $\Lambda(i,k)\cdot\Lambda(k,j)=\Lambda_x(i,k)\Lambda_x(k,j)+\Lambda_y(i,k) \Lambda_y(k,j)$. The $\textbf{G}_i$ vectors equal the gradients.

Comment: Maybe then $\Lambda_x^T\Lambda_x + \Lambda_y^T\Lambda_y$

Comment: @OliverAmundsen ah yes, I never noticed that. That looks right.

Comment: OK. So (1) to get $c$ I should do: $c = \Lambda_x^T G_x + \Lambda_y^T G_y$. (2) then $c$ is $n \times n$, and so $B$. $A$ is also $n\times n$?

Comment: @OliverAmundsen (1) yes. (2) $c$ will actually be $n\times 1$ but $B$ will indeed be $n\times n$. I'm not sure what '$A$' refers to though...

Comment: ozo, but the $\bf G$'s and the $\Lambda$'s are both $n\times n$, right? for they span the whole domain, am I wrong? if that's the case then $c$ should also be $n\times n$. Sorry $A$ is $a$.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen $G_x$ and $G_y$ are each $n\times 1$. $\Lambda_x$ and $\Lambda_y$ are $n\times n$. And $c$ and $a$ are both $n\times 1$.